# How to check whether a string contains all the parts of another string?

Tags: java, string

```
String str1 = "+91 123 45";
String str2 = "12345"; 

if (str2.matches("(.*)" +str1.replaceAll("\\s+", "")))
{
    System.out.print("Matched" );
}
```

How to make the if condition true? str2 may or may not contain '+' and spaces depending on the user. Above is just an example for testing.

Comment: You don't need to write `new String` This is not C++.

Comment: Do you mean `str2.replaceAll(" ", "").contains(str1)`?

Comment: I want to check whether str2 contains all the numbers in str1 and if yes, if should return true. str1 may or may not include '+' and white spaces and if it does, I need to eliminate white spaces and optional '+'.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, my question had some minor errors.

Comment: I see it the other way around now so `str1.replaceAll(" ", "").contains(str2)` assuming the `+` is always at the start.

Comment: Yes, If there is a plus, it will always be at the start otherwise the string will be 91 123 45

Comment: So you can remove the `+` or not, it won't get in the way of `str1`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!